# FHIR: Is there a way to search for Active Practitioners at an Organisation?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I can search for active **PractitionerRole** resources that match a certain organisation by doing this:

```
/PractitionerRole?active=true&organization.identifier=ORG123
```

What I'd like to get back is *just* the related **Practioner** resources for this query

If I try something like:

```
/Practitioner?_has:PractitionerRole:practitioner:organization.identifier=ORG123&_has:PractitionerRole:practitioner:active=true
```

This does not return what I want as it (correctly) processes the organization + active check separately.

The nearest I can get to at the moment is to add an _include to the first query above. E.g.

```
/PractitionerRole?active=true&organization.identifier=ORG123&_include=PractitionerRole:practitioner
```

but this obviously returns **PractionerRole** (mode=match) resources in addition to the included **Practitioner** (mode=include) resources, and so additional client side processing will be required to discard the unwanted **PractitionerRole** resources

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

For the record, my target FHIR implementation is a VONK 3.9.1.0 server

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use _filter (which few systems support)